# Compare two data points inside the tooltip in a Highcharts combination chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a combination bar-line chart sharing a single Y axis.

The data points for both the bar and the line chart always share the same Y values. I'd like to be able to calculate the difference between the two X values in the tooltip.

Here's the chart I'm working with:

[Combo Chart](http://jsfiddle.net/7RQU4/)

Comment: Can you give an example ? (like what should be the output when seeing particular tooltip )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it to work.  The trick was in the shared and formatter properties of tooltip:

```
       tooltip: {

            shared: true,

            formatter: function() {


                var s= this.points[1].y - this.points[0].y;



                return s;

            }

        },
```