# Adding Extra data in Basic Line Chart ToolTip.

Tags: ios, objective-c, highcharts, tooltip, linechart

I followed this Basic Line Chart :
[Line Chart](https://www.highcharts.com/ios/demo/line-basic)

I wanted to Achieve this kind of ToolTip..
[image]

Currently Acc to Tutorial Code ,This could be achieved.

[image]

There are Two things I wanted to achieve ;

1. Remove X-Axis Tooltip value.(Its coming by default).
2. Add Extra data to y-axis tooltip data like this (29/3543). I have data in different arrays. How to put these values in tooltip from different arrays.

Comment: check this https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormat will be helpfull

Comment: solution from your earlier [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49379161/3898339) does not help

Comment: `tooltip.formatter` (https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter) allows you to specify the full content of tooltip and access other variables. Here's a solution for similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747277/compare-two-data-points-inside-the-tooltip-in-a-highcharts-combination-chart?rq=1

Comment: have you done this?

Comment: No, At that time this was not much of priority so leaved that.